# What tools allow me to present man pages as formatted HTML on a web server?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, man, http, html

What tools exist to make man pages available on a system available via HTTP and link topics together such that references in the `SEE ALSO` sections and elsewhere will become hyperlinks in the HTML representation of the man pages?

I'm using Debian (6) and Ubuntu (10.04, 10.10) currently, so existing packages would be preferred, but I'll also go for any other solutions if they are clearly superior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The debian package `dwww` give access to all the documentation installed by the packages, included the manual pages.

After installing the package with your favorite package manager, you will be able to browse the local documentation with your navigator on `http://localhost/dwww/`.

By default, access to this URL is restricted to local connections but you can change this restriction in the configuration file `/etc/dwww/apache.conf` (don't forget to reload apache after changing something in this file).

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try tonight. Let's see whether other suggestions will come up as well.